# The label number for a longtable in a landscape enviroment skips by one - help?

Tags: longtable, landscape

I have typeset a `longtable` in a `landscape` in each of 2 subsubsections right after one another (in the appendix of my document, actually).

There are just a few sentences in each subsubsection before each `\begin{landscape}` but the captionlabels start of course with "Table A.1" for the first table. But after that it is "Table A.3" for the next one. How does that happen? I have never experienced that with LaTeX before. :(

**edit** I use `\captionof{table}[Caption for Lot]{Longer caption}` for each longtable.

Relevant lines from the `.aux`-file (I only replaced the actual content of the caption in this code, nothing else):

```
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {A.1}{\ignorespaces contentDUMMY}{11}{table.A.1}}
\newlabel{tab:AAA}{{A.1}{11}{contentDUMMY }{table.A.1}{}}
\mph@setcol{ii:11}{\mph@nr}
\mph@setcol{ii:12}{\mph@nr}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {A.1.1.2}contentDUMMY}{13}{subsubsection.A.1.1.2}}
\newlabel{contentDUMMY}{{A.1.1.2}{13}{contentDUMMY}{subsubsection.A.1.1.2}{}}
\mph@setcol{ii:13}{\mph@nr}
\gdef \LT@iii {\LT@entry 
    {1}{30.32938pt}\LT@entry 
    {1}{27.90813pt}\LT@entry 
    {1}{51.8908pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{36.35272pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{30.26454pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{30.26454pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{30.26454pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{36.35272pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{36.35272pt}\LT@entry 
    {1}{58.51552pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{39.3968pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{42.42996pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{39.3968pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{42.42996pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{30.26454pt}\LT@entry 
    {4}{30.26454pt}}
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {A.3}{\ignorespaces contentDUMMY}{14}{table.A.3}}
```

Comment: Please post the code (compilable) that generates this aux-output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `longtable` without a caption, but the longtable increases the counter `table` anyway. This is the reason why a following `table` or `longtable` environment *with*  a caption has the wrong number. Use

```
\begin{longtable}{..}%% Which has _no_ caption
%% No caption here
...
\end{longtable}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}%%%%% decrease the counter

\begin{table}%% Or a tabular _with_ a caption
\caption{...}
...
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}%% a long tabular with a caption
\caption{...}\\
...
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Actually I use `\captionof` for each longtable. Sorry I forgot to state that in the op which I is now updated.

Comment: Why `captionof`?? Use `\caption` inside the `longtable`!

Comment: I was not aware `landscape` was a float. Well now I know.

Comment: `landscape` is _not_ a float!

Comment: `longtable` is not a float, but it provides the capability to set a caption.

Comment: Oh wow. I never knew one could/should set `longtable`s this way. If anyone wanders upon this: `texdoc longtable`, see top of page 10.

Comment: Hm, actually... despite using `\caption` only once before `\endfirsthead` and not before `\endhead`, the caption gets set on each page. This is not working well. :/

Comment: requiring a table caption is _such_ a bad design. Who made that package?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry I am so confused by this. Is it intentional the caption gets set on each page of the continued longtable? This is new to me. Not saying it is bad... just new. :) Btw, this does not change whether I use `\caption[]{}\\` betweet `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead` or not.

Comment: if you don't have `\caption` in the `\endhead` section then you won't have a caption on continuation pages, if you do, you will

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It works now. Somebody must have had secretly accessed my .tex-document and built in some little frustrating error. I would have never done that.

Comment: Man do I love me some longtable these days. That package is awesome.

Comment: @henry: I wonder who wrote `longtable`. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda I know it was David, hence my really strong love for it. :)